# How do I orient the "outlet" side of a voltage stepdown converter relative to the connecting circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, buck

I've created a circuit diagram for a wheeled robot. This is my first circuit diagram as a mechanical engineer, and I'm a little confused on the current flow convention for the voltage stepdown converter (VSC) highlit in yellow in the diagram below.

As I understand, passive elements are oriented opposite to active elements, such that the current by popular convention flows out of the positive terminal of active elements and into the positive terminal of passive elements. But how does this work for the VSC? I assume the "inlet" side connects to the battery positive-to-positive, since the VSC is seen as a passive element relative to the battery in that sense, but how do I know how to orient the "outlet" side of the VSC relative to the rest of the circuit?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your statement "passive elements are oriented opposite to active elements" is incorrect.

The positive output of a power source is connected to the positive input of any load.  The positive terminal of a polarized capacitor must be more positive than the negative terminal, and so for almost any other component.

You may be confused by Zener diodes, where the cathode is connected to the more positive supply voltage.  Zener diodes depend on their reverse breakdown voltage for correct operation so must be connected "backwawrds".

Comment: By that, I was just referencing what I learned in my college circuits course. It sounds like we're on the same page there. I was specifically targeting the voltage stepdown converter with my question because I'm not confident in whether the positive terminal of its "outlet" side should be connected to the positive terminal of the following loads.

Comment: The positive output terminal of the stepdown converter must definitely be connected to the positive terminal of any loads.